# Github API: how to get organisation's repos sorted by contributors?

Tags: git, api, github, github-api

Is there a way to get an organization's repos (say Facebook) sorted by the number of contributors each repo has.

Right now I can do it by manual calculation (that is, loop over each repo for the organization and for each ask the api to return its contributor list and that's how I sort by whichever has the longest list of contributors). 
Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way.